# Embed image into an email when building a workflow in designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, email

At my witts end.

I have created a workflow to send a happy birthday picture. But no matter what I tried the picture doesn't display. Please see if I'm doing something wrong.

I uploaded the picture onto our sharepoint site in an image library (as one poster suggested). I have tried with both a .png and a .jpeg

I then go to designer and set the variable to  (Where picture link is the Http site - I didn't want to add the full link here)

I then go to email body and add lookup like this
[image]

So now it looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas of why the picture is still not showing??

All I get is an email with nothing in the body, all blank not even an error message.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the variable birthday to this:

```
<img src="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/michael/Pictures/1.png" />
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly like i have it. And the message is still blank. Any other ideas where I can start to look for the problem?